# change default event rule for codepipeline via terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I want to trigger codepipeline based on custom event rule - trigger pipeline on specific change in codecommit based on commit message.

I created the lambda function that do this logic and update the default event rule.

This configuration done manually and working.

Now I want to automate it via terraform -> create codepipeline, lambda, custom event rule.

I can't find a way to change the default event rule that created automatically for pipeline to my custom rule.

How I can do it via terraform?

Comment: You have to create full CW rule yourself in TF with your custom event.

Comment: I create CW rule via terraform, my problem is to change the default one that created automatically with pipeline to my custom.